# How to symbolize/represent overlapping line shapefiles (cycling routes) as points/markers/symbols?

Tags: qgis-3

[image]I am currently trying to visualize bike trails and cycling routes as polyline shapefiles on a map. For the the sake of clarity, I intent to link the different cycling routes with point vectors (or represent the routes as point vectors / markers). I would like to do it like outdooractive.com does it: https://www.outdooractive.com/mobile/de/routes/#fu=1

Does anybody know whether and how this is possible in QGIS / QGis2Web?

Comment: please add a screen shot of the effect you would like to achieve - the map you link to is unclear (and vanishes after translation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The screenshot demonstrates what I‘d like to achieve. — The number 2 next to the city Luzern is a cluster for two other bicycle symbols that represent the starting point of a route and deliver additional information (length of the route etc.) if you click on it.